# how to get iframe to fill entire page 100% and top:4px?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've been coming here for a while, and only asked 1 question before. And I have designed many sites. But the only thing I do not fully get is 'iFrames'. They mess with my head a tad bit.

.:What i'm trying to achieve:.

***note: I do not have ownership of the origin of the iFrames domain... It should be irrelevant since you are simply taking one page, and showing it on another. Their External Styling still shows their page how it should. I know this because i've done it.***

1) I need to know how to get the iFrame to show on my site as a FULL PAGE.
   I know there are ALOT of topics on here about iFrames, but 1) they are outdated. 2) they do not apply to me/my site. I've tried everything, and yet it all seems futile.

.:Example:.

When user(s) go to http://www.example.com/news.php, the page should load the content from another news site. i.e cnn, wn, cbs...

I have figured this out before, so please no1 tell me all that rubble about not having ownership of contents, then I cannot reach my goal.

I don't remember how I wrote it, but I know there was NO CSS styling whatsoever. It was something VERY similar to:

```
    <body style="scrolling:no;>
    <iframe src='http://www.example.com' 
    style='position:absolute; top:4px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; 
    z-index:999' onload='sendParams();' frameborder='no' scrolling='auto'>
    </iframe>
    </body>
```

What I am not getting is: No matter what style I use to customize the iFrame, it seems to be held within a box about the `size= 867x155`.
I even tried to put the iFrame itself within a `DIV`, and `DIV` set to: W- `100%` H- `100%`.

when I tried the CSS approach, the marginheight/width was ignored. Also, a different body style of `margin="0"`, was futile; yet again.

Answer (score 18):

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/cgXcR/

The HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://www.cnn.com" height="100%"></iframe>​
```

The CSS:

```
body, html { width:100% ;
    height:100% ;
    overflow:hidden ;
}

iframe { width:100% ;
        height:100% ;
    border:none ;
}
```

Comment: It looks about right. I'm going to implement it into site now, I will try it out.  But, is there a way to have it `top:4px`?
I need to have a little space at the top for my drop-down.

Comment: just change the iframe CSS to:

Comment: iframe { width:100% ;
        height:100% ;
    border:none ;
    position:relative ;
    top:4px ;
}

Comment: Well, it was just that. It looked right, but still a like-same problem. If you look at the picture at the link, it shows that the iFrame is yet again cut off. There's nothing else on my page, and no ?php set to this url. So, idk why it does not show. I believe I used z-index, but I do not see why I have to, as there is nothing else that can interfere with it in any way/shape/form.

[http://prntscr.com/ee2l5]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zDzTk/ it uses the site you're trying to frame. You have SO much extra CSS that isn't need on that page. Just pare it down to the HTML and CSS in this jfiddle. Nothing else.

Comment: Hun, I don't have any CSS layout on that page. It was just what you have given me above^^

Can you elaborate more thoroughly? I put the syntax in, but it still shows up the same asin the SS I took. I may have to position it absolute.

Comment: view-source:http://4o.yolasite.com/world.php That is the source code of that page. You'll see there is FAR more there than just the few lines of HTML and CSS needed to get the job done.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant? Yeah, I see what you mean now. I didn't understand what you meant by "SO much extra CSS". LoL.
Ummm, that's because they are my host. But all that extra CSS & HTML is void. What only applies is from `line-222`
                
<div id="I141_html"><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

to `line-263`
        
        </html>

And that's what I meant to tell you before. It may seem like alot of coding, but look in between those lines. The only thing I have aside from the code you gave,

Comment: is the   
`<script src="http://cdn.wibiya.com/dew/the/Tool_dew/Loader_1220221.jjjjs" type="text/javascript"></script>`
But I added extra "J's" to null the JS. So, I do not see why nothing is working... :|

Comment: the jsfiddle provided in this answer doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 10):

Ok, well I would like to thank Cynthia for her help.

But if anyone is looking for a simplistic answer that ACTUALLY works, then check this out:

Like the ORIGINAL inquiry: **FULL iFrame**

***A resolve using CSS***

```
<blah>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {scrolling:no;
}
    iframe {position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.wn.com" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

**Notice the *`positioning`* & *`z-index`***

***Note: This can be wrote through MARK-UP ONLY. You do not have to use CSS, but it makes more sense to do this because not only are you trying to have everything show correctly on yoru website; by using CSS to customize your iFrame, you open more windows for each individual frame within your webpage. If you are like me, and only using ONE iFrame, then you should simply use MARK-UP. But, if you have more than 1 [or 1 frame has many within], you should use CSS to specifically `ID` each frame. ***

Also, if anyone is wondering how to use MARK-UP only, simply swap what's in the CSS, and put within the `<iframe></iframe>` but use single quotes

***`The Antarctican`***

Comment: Where is this "scrolling" css attribute coming from? and in which browser is it supported?

Comment: As far as I know there is know scrolling attribute in css.